# Bootstrap with a fixed width grid and images that should span the window width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to display the image outside the containers `width`, filling up to right edge of the browser.

At the moment I'm doing this with JavaScript, but I feels and looks clumsy, and SEO is unfriendly because of missing ALT-tags and also introduces problems when the css triggers different viewport settings for smaller screens.

Is there a documentation chapter I've missed?

My current set up:

```
<div class="container-fluid screen-image" style="background: url('image.png') no-repeat;" data-position-object="screen1">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      my content
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" id="screen1">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javscript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setScreenPositions();

    $(window).on('resize', function() {
       setScreenPositions();
    });

    function setScreenPositions() {
        $('.screen-image').each(function() {
            var $this = $(this),
                $positionObject = $('#' + $this.attr('data-position-object'));

            $this.css('background-position', $positionObject.position().left + 'px 60px');
        });
    }
});
```

To better illustrate what I'm after, I've put my Word drawing skills to the test since I'm not at my own computer at the moment ;)
[image]

Comment: This is just for decoration right? -

Comment: I'm aiming to design a landing/product page with some in-app screenshots along the text. So for that I'd like to have the images span to the full right (or left if the content is on the right).

Comment: Can we change the HTML? Can we use background images instead of actual images. Are any heights known?

Comment: Html can be changed. Keeping SEO in mind I think img is preferred over the background-image. Heights vary based upon device.

Comment: No special CSS at the moment. Just following Bootstrap's grid system to create the view.

Comment: As far as I know there are not built-in classes to do what you need. You should handle it with your own css, handling the various devices from CSS @media. Maybe you can work it out with z-index and overflow

Comment: My answer solves your problem with just a couple lines of CSS.

Comment: @RyanWheale great answer, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `vw` unit to set the image width to 50% of the viewport width. You will need to zero out the padding on grid cell which wraps the image. The `vw` unit is [supported by all major browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units):

[image]

```css
.row .col-img-wrap {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
.col-img-wrap img {
  width: 50vw;
}
.col-align-right img {
  float: right;
}
/* not needed */
.container {
  border: 1px red solid
}
.row {
  background-color: #bca;
}
.col-xs-12 { 
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3em;
  background-color: #abc;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
        This is some content inside a col-xx-6 cell
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-img-wrap">
        <img src="//lorempixel.com/1000/300" alt="SEO Text" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        This is some content inside a col-xx-12 cell
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-img-wrap col-align-right">
        <img src="//lorempixel.com/1000/300" alt="SEO Text" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        This is some content inside a col-xx-6 cell
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, this is exactly what I'm looking for. +1A and I hereby grant you the bounty.

Answer (score 4):

Try the following HTML structure:

```
<div class="container-fluid screen-image">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-offset-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 image-content">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            my content
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            content 2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then use this CSS:

```
    .screen-image {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        padding: 0; /* Cover the full screen width */
    }

    .screen-image .image-content {
        height: 400px; /* Dummy height. Change with your desired height */
        background: url("image.png") no-repeat;
        background-size: cover; /* Anything that suits your needs */
        background-position: 0 0;
    }

    .content-wrapper {
        position: relative; /* Go on top of the screen-image */
    }
```

Here is a quick explanation:

- We set `position: absolute` on the background image container. We don't want it to push the content down.
- Screen-image padding of 0 will null the default .container-fluid padding thus making the image cover the whole screen.
- For the content we'll need position relative. Otherwise it will appear under the `.screen-image` element.
- On the `.screen-image .image-content` we need to set `.col-sm-12` to make it cover the whole screen on mobile. We don't have 2 columns there so it makes sense to cover the whole screen with the background image.

### EDIT (img tag)

Example with SEO friendly image tag: http://codepen.io/avladov/pen/bpKvYd

Comment: In this way I still haven't got an actual `<img/>` for SEO purposes. But I'll give your solution with some modifications a try as soon as I get to my laptop again. Thanks so far for now.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like this happening because you have used **container** inside **container-fluid**. Please try replacing your **container** class with **row** class. It will solve your problem for sure.

Best luck.

Comment: That would still not solve the problem for the content to be centered (with the container width). Thanks for your help though, +1 for the effort.

Comment: add text-center class along with row, That will solve that problem too.

Answer (score 4):

According to [**Bootstrap Docs**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid), your HTML is incorrect,

- you shouldn't have a `.container` right after a `.container-fluid`
- after a `.container` you should have a `.row`

With the correct HTML and from what I've understood, you just need to reset the bootstrap default `padding` given in the `col-` classes.

**UPDATE**

You will need to give a `width` to your `container-fluid` and then use `position:relative` (which bootstrap already have in `-col`) and using `calc()` along with viewport units.

**Note** I use `!important` just for the demo get simpler. in Production **avoid** using `!important` by getting more specific on the CSS rule.

```css
body {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 0, .5) !important
}
.container-fluid {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
  width: 70% /*adjust the width accordling to your needs*/
}
[class$="-6"] {
  /*all classes ending with "-6" */
  border: 1px green solid;
  padding: 0 !important;
}
/* the -70vw should be equal to the % width of container-fluid */
.row div:first-of-type {
  left: calc(-70vw + 80%) 
}
.row div:last-of-type {
  right: calc(-70vw + 80%)
}
img {
  opacity: .65
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
      my content
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="//lorempixel.com/1000/300" />
      <!-- this should size up to right end of the window, meaning it should overflow .col-md-6 and .container -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You say I can't have a container right after a container-fluid. But I need to image to be fluid as in your example, but the content in the left container (col-xs-6) I want to be in the containers with, not fully spanning to the left.

Comment: I'm not at the computer at the moment but still your comment was a bit confused to me.. Can you please explain me a little better? So I can help you better

Comment: Hi Dippas, I mean I want a page where I'm using `container` instead of `container-fluid`, because I want to the content to be centered. Within that container I want for example a `col-md-6` to put content in the left 50% of the width of that `container`. For the other 50% I would like to show a product-image (web app screenshot) that sizes up over the whole right page (meaning, outside `container` to the most right pixel on the screen). Is this better to understand? I'll add an img to the question as well.

Comment: ASAP I'll try to get back to you. I'm in lunch time now.

Comment: Ah great! I've added a picture to the question. If you have any questions, please let me know!

Comment: @Ben I updated the answer with comments inside the CSS

Comment: Thanks for all your effort Dippas, but I'm still stuck with the fact that the content is not rendered in the container (that's why I added a container in a container-fluid). Since the bounty award period almost expires I had to choose the answer that did the exact trick. Still, +1 (10 if I could;)) Have a nice day. Thanks again.

Comment: @Ben it was just an example I didn't notice you want just `img` offset the container, when I updated the answer (my bad I know). I thought that  was just a demo. My code does what you want, it just needs a different class for `img` containers only.... but OK. Even in my code you don't get horizontal scrollbar ;)

Answer (score 3):

It's not the prettiest solution but it does work. It's not as fluid as I would like to see.

http://codepen.io/iMarketingGuy/pen/BKVmMj

CSS

```
html, body {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.row {
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.row img {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.floatRight {
    float: right !important;
}

.image {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

.image img {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

JavaScript

```
var containerWidth = $(".container").width();

if (containerWidth > 750) {
    $("#row-1-image-col").css({ "position": "absolute", "right": "0", "margin-right": "-15px" });
    $("#row-3-image-col").css({ "position": "absolute", "left": "0", "margin-left": "-15px" });
} else {
    $("#row-1-image-col").css({ "position": "relative", "padding": "0px 15px" });
    $("#row-3-image-col").css({ "position": "relative", "padding": "0px 15px" });
}

var row1ImageColHeight = $("#row-1-image-col").height();
var row1TextColHeight = $("#row-1-text-col").height();

if (row1ImageColHeight >= row1TextColHeight) {
    $("#row-1").css("height", row1ImageColHeight + "px");
} else {
    $("#row-1").css("height", row1TextColHeight + "px");
}

var row3ImageColHeight = $("#row-3-image-col").height();
var row3TextColHeight = $("#row-3-text-col").height();

if (row3ImageColHeight >= row3TextColHeight) {
    $("#row-3").css("height", row3ImageColHeight + "px");
} else {
    $("#row-3").css("height", row3TextColHeight + "px");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I'm not really seeking for a javascript solution. As I mentioned that seems a bit hacky to me. A Bootstrap/CSS solution has been given, maybe it's interesting to read for you as well. Thanks again. +1 for your effort.

Answer (score 3):

end container before full size width section, dont mix container with container-fluid. you can have multiple container( container and container fluid one after another. Dont use js if you can use css. Use bootstrap grid. Also you can use flex grid for more complicated aligned grids if you dont have to cover older browsers. If you want full screen background, use backgroung with cover property on higher elemrnt ex. on body tag.
If you want to have full width solution under centered grid, put container inside the div with image bg.

html:

```
<div class="screen-image">
<div class="container">
<div class="col-xs-6">lorem impsum dolor
    </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">lorem ipsum dolor 
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.screen-image {

background-image:  url("http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/colorful-triangles-background_yB0qTG6.jpg");

background-position: right top;
background-size: 50% 60px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;}
```

also you can put img just like regular content inside the col-xs-6 - it will overflow, and use overflow hidden on ex body to remove the horizontal sliders.

the solution i would choose would be background image set as 50% of the window size in css. - it will be aligned with the grid then.
also you can manage how it works on different resolutions by media queries.

Comment: This still leaves the `img` tag unused and for SEO purposes I want that in. +1 for your effort though. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't think you need javascript. When it comes to bootstrap you just need to think of all the pieces in a puzzle. 
`container-fluid` makes it possible for full width screen. 
Adding `container col-md-6` makes one column with max width. Then a `container-fluid col-md-6` makes a half page column with no max width for images to the edge. Here is my codepen, a more concise version from the guy above.

http://codepen.io/MrNagoo/pen/jqvyeP

Of course, it's pretty easy to make your own containers with css while still using bootstrap.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but your solution still misses the fact that I want to put the content in a container (as I later showed with the image in the question). Thanks for your help though, +1 for your effort.

Comment: Thanks, I see what you mean. I went ahead and updated my codepen. It is pretty efficient and doesn't require overriding any bootstrap css. The only thing you need to do is add the bootstrap media queries to adjust how you want it to look. Whether you use it or not I just wanted to make it work :)

Answer (score 2):

First, I'd recommend not use two containers (which *doubles* the *grid gutter width*), but use only one **container** and also use a **row** in order to have every column aligned as the were initially made.

Something like below:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique unde odio assumenda omnis, sunt, quam cum, animi minus fugit, voluptate adipisci illum officiis in non. Animi officia eligendi quos? Est?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="image"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, I quite changed a bit how the divs should be ordered.

Now, how I would solve your issue, is putting a **div** inside that column that you want make an image outside the container.

You can use an **img** tag instead of the div.

I will show you an example by using the **div** and applying **background-image** to it.

We can achieve the desired effect, if we apply the CSS below:

```
.image {
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/1024/768');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 500px;
  width: calc(50vw - 15px);
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .image {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

**NOTE:** We can use viewport width unit to the **div** inside the column and just take off the *grid gutter width* by by calculating it the way above.

**Explanation:** Viewport width (**vw**) is a unit which calculates the whole width of your current screen, never minding what size does the parent div have.

**Can I Use it?** vw is now supported in most modern browsers.
http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

As for the **@media** query, I assumet in smaller screens than **md** image should be applied 100%.

You can see this working, in the Codepen below:
http://codepen.io/ArdianPerlaska/pen/dMqWKp

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but not exactly what I was looking for. +1 for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

i acomplised it with a absolute position element as a sibling of the container.
see codepen:

```
 .absolute {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px; //this needs to be fixed always, can be customized through media queries
  .white, .gray {
    float: left;
        width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #e3e3e3;
    @media (min-width:576px){  //make it match with the switch columns/trigger with columns changes
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    }
  }
  .gray {
    background-color: gray; 
    background-image: url('http://www.dailyfreepsd.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/sunset-blurred-background-freebie.jpg');
    background-size:cover;    
  }
}


.fixed-height{
  height: 200px; //this needs to be fixed always, can be customized through media queries
  .title, .lead, .list{
    color:white;
  }

}
```

[working pen here](http://codepen.io/c42705/pen/JNPmbm)